# Get Image size from 4 pixel position using JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image-processing, canvas

[image]

Can anybody here who help me to find width and height from the four corners, like in this picture i have 4 places

```
W - Width
H - Height

1 - 156W/116H
2 - 337W/54H
3 - 136W/312H
4 - 244/279H
```

Is there any one who can provide a formula for finding the width and height from four positions using JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: Are you trying to get the area in the image, or the actual area of the photographed object, corrected for viewing angle? If it's the latter, you'll first need to calculate the viewing angle of the square shape given the angle of the edges, which you can do like this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071072/calculate-the-viewing-angle-on-a-square-3d-calc

Comment: It would be a nice idea to attach some code to show what you have worked on so far. That way we can help you better and also shows research and initiative on your end :) also welcome to SO

Comment: We cannot write the complete code for you, but are happy to help when you stumble upon an actual problem. Did you try anything? What solutions did you look at and how did they not work for you or which problems did you encounter with them? Also, indeed, it's not clear to me what your actual question is: you want a pixel area? The actual area in RL is difficult due to the obliquity and unknown camera parameters - though one can make a few educated guesses which don't need image processing at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the area in the image, which is a distorted rectangle due to perspective angle, you can approximate its width and height by taking the higher difference between coordinates. According to [Alisher Gafurov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43087043/6002745)'s response :

```
point_01 = {'x':156, 'y': 116};
point_02 = {'x':337, 'y': 54};
point_03 = {'x':136, 'y': 312};
point_04 = {'x':244, 'y': 279};

rectangle = {
  'height': Math.max(point_03.y - point_01.y, point_04.y - point_02.y),
  'width' : Math.max(point_02.x - point_01.x, point_04.x - point_02.x)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If we talking about the rectangle (all corners = 90°). And if you 4 points coordinates calculate from left top corner of the parent object/container/page. The rectangle dimension will be:

```
point_01 = {'x':156, 'y': 116};
point_02 = {'x':337, 'y': 54};
point_03 = {'x':136, 'y': 312};
point_04 = {'x':244, 'y': 279};

rectangle = {
   'height':  point_03.y - point_01.y,
   'width' : point_02.x - point_01.x
};
```